# Setting User Control DropdownList Selected Value from Calling page Code behind

Tags: c#

How do I set User Control DropdownList Selected Value from Calling page Code behind.

```
public string BirthCountryId
{
    get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlBirthCountry.SelectedValue) ? null 
                 : ddlBirthCountry.SelectedValue; }
    set { ddlBirthCountry.SelectedValue = value; }
}
```

Comment: what are the steps to set selected value of dropdownlist of user control from calling page

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *from calling page code behind*?

Comment: actually I want to set dropdown selected value of a user control from another aspx page.

Comment: That makes no sense. So you have page1.aspx and page2.aspx but you want to change something from page1.aspx in page2.aspx? And will this be triggered through a UI?

Comment: let me clear the issue. I have a Dropdown control in Countries.ascx which loads country lists at page load event and that user control is referenced in Users.aspx page. I want to set Dropdown list selected value from Users.aspx page code behid.